# Apply price filter in JPA query

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring boot JPA. I want to filter results by low price to the high price of the product. The query is working fine without involving the price attribute, but when i add filter by price, it gives an empty list. However, the query is working in MySQL workbench and giving appropriate results.
Can someone help with this issue that why I am getting an empty result?

Repository:

```
@Query("SELECT new com.example.demo.model.CustomerProductDTO(vp.vendorproductid, p.name, vp.price, CASE quantitykg WHEN NULL THEN vp.quantitybundle ELSE vp.quantitykg END, p.image) FROM vendorproduct vp JOIN vp.product p ON p.productid = vp.productid WHERE vp.vendorid=:vendorid AND vp.price>=:minprice AND vp.price<=:maxprice ORDER BY vp.price")
    
List<CustomerProductDTO> getProductsLowToHigh(String vendorid, float minprice, float maxprice, Pageable p);
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/products/{vendorid}")
public List<CustomerProductDTO> getCustomerProducts(@PathVariable("vendorid") String vendorid,
    @RequestParam Map<String, String> map) {

    List<CustomerProductDTO> customerProductDTOs = new ArrayList<CustomerProductDTO>();
    Pageable p = PageRequest.of(0, 10);

    if (map.get("minprice").equals("null") && map.get("maxprice").equals("null")) {
        customerProductDTOs = vendorProductRepo.getProductsLowToHigh(vendorid, p);
    }
    else {
        Float minPrice = Float.valueOf(map.get("minprice"));
        Float maxPrice = Float.valueOf(map.get("maxprice"));

        customerProductDTOs = vendorProductRepo.getProductsLowToHigh(vendorid, minPrice, maxPrice, p);
    }       
    return customerProductDTOs;
}
```

Returned DTO:

```
public class CustomerProductDTO {
    
    int vendorproductid;
    String name;
    float price;
    int quantity;
    String image;    
    int stockQuantity;    
    boolean isOutOfStock;

        public CustomerProductDTO() {}
        public CustomerProductDTO(int vendorproductid, String name, float price, int quantity, String image) {
        super();
        this.vendorproductid = vendorproductid;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.image = image;
    }

    //getter and setter
}
```

Comment: What is the exact query you're trying to call (what are the parameter values)? BTW `float` is not exactly a data type suitable for storing monetary values. I'd strongly recommend switching to `BigDecimal` instead

Comment: I have already mentioned everything in question. Ok Thanks for the advice.

Comment: can you please add Entity classes?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller above the line,

```
customerProductDTOs = vendorProductRepo.getProductsLowToHigh(vendorid, minPrice, maxPrice, p)
```

Add the code given below, so that this annotation helps you sort the records you have received in either ascending or descending order and also you can mention the exact field which you want to sort out.

```
@ElementCollection
@OrderBy("position.code DESC")
```